# Getting issue with Snapchat Marketing API for granularity as DAY and TOTAL

Tags: time-series, timezone, ads, snapchat, granularity

I am trying to call Snapchat Marketing API through postman for Ads stats and I've seen many of us facing this issue especially for date timezone but this issue specific for granularity where if it's TOTAL then the data shows up and if its DAY the data strangely seems 0

https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/ads//stats?start_time=2024-02-01T00:00:00.000-05:00&end_time=2024-02-26T00:00:00.000-05:00&granularity=DAY

I'm not able to figure out what's happening or if changing the format of date or timezone then get the error like:

Timeseries queries with DAY granularity must have a start time that is the start of day (00:00:00) for the account's timezone. This account's timezone is: America/Toronto

I have tried a lot of possible combination of start time and end time
and even used omit_empty but still facing the issue. If someone is aware of this specific issue, please let me know..

I'll share the screenshot for your reference

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at the `finalized_data_end_time` in the response to the request with no date range filter, I think you may need to expand the cover of your range to include it.